# Spring integration DSL CPU usage

Tags: spring-integration, spring-dsl

We use Spring integration DSL pretty heavily in our app and am currently troubleshooting high CPU usage. Looking into the threads that are consuming high CPU, noticed that spring integration call stack is too deep, more than 500+ lines.  Our spring integration flows are long and complex and speak for the deep stack,  but am trying to see if that can be a potential cause for the high CPU usage. Any thoughts on how spring integration DSL can impact CPU will help.

Thanks
Zafer

Comment: There are some known issues with aggregating very large groups of messages; some of these are resolved in recent releases; some others may need adjustments to configuration. This is generally not an issue for small groups. If you think that might be one of your scenarios, share some configuration. And tell us what versions you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The deep stack is unlikely to be the problem; I suggest you profile your application with YourKit or similar, to see where the time is being spent.

Comment: Thanks Gary, Will look further.